# Update Item Product Options After Order Placed

Tags: magento, observer-pattern

I'm working on an observer that needs to add (a) serial key(s) to each item in the cart once an order is placed.

I'm listening to the event sales_model_service_quote_submit_success right now.

I've been able to access the order, get a list of the items, iterate through them, and get the product options. My code fails either when I try to setProductOptions or save--I'm not sure which, maybe it's both.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// Get access to order information
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);

// Get the items from the order
$items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
    // Pretend here is the call that fetches the serial keys for this item and stores them in $keyString

    // If we actually received the keys in a string, store them with the item
    if (!empty($keyString))
    {
        $productOptions = array();
        if (count($item->getProductOptions()))
        {
            $productOptions = $item->getProductOptions();
        }
        $productOptions['keys'] = $keyString;

        $item->setProductOptions($productOptions);
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I have forgotten or done wrong? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no such observer , at least i didn't find it from codebase, here's what you can use

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_service_quote_submit_before', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_model_service_quote_submit_after', array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$quote));
```

and in your observer method

```
/**
 * 
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * 
 */
public function setShippingDefaults(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
}
```

the idea is that if you do it in before-action then you won't need to call save and if you do it in after-action then you do and if you do it in before action you might just end in endless loop if you are not careful.

Comment: Anton, I appreciate your input. I have two thoughts about this approach. First, the event was dispatching just fine, so it's not that the observer isn't being used, it's a matter of which event. Second, I need to confirm that the order was successful before I can release the keys to the customer, so performing an order, change, and resave in some form is basically inevitable.

Comment: Anton, although some of what you told me didn't make sense for my specific situation, the new line of code for accessing the order variable worked ($order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();). I'm not sure why the variable structure is different or has different access rights, but this new way of accessing the variable did the trick. Thanks for taking the time to look into my problem!

Comment: @Anton, As you mentioned there is no such observer  sales_model_service_quote_submit_success but I have found this observer in  app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml.   Do you have any explanation on this.?

Comment: @shashank why comment something that might have been changed after 4 years or is just a bug

Comment: @Anton I am new with magento. I just want to be sure that this observer exist now or not.